# Backbone Marionette module starting, regardless of startWithParent setting

Tags: marionette

I'm checking out Backbone Marionette and it seems promising for my current project. However, when adding modules they seem to auto start, regardless of the startWithParent setting. Here's a piece of the code I'm having issues with (part of it is actually copied from the Marionette docs):

```
var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

var fooModule = app.module('fooModule', {
      startWithParent: false,

      define: function(){
          console.log('I should not auto start');
      }
    });

app.start();
```

I'm expecting "I should not auto start" not to appear in my console, but it does. To me it seems I should execute...

```
app.module('fooModule').start()
```

...before this message should appear.

I'm using Backbone.Marionette 1.0.2, Backbone 1.0 and Underscore 1.4.4.

Any clues as to why this is happening? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [module initializers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#module-initializers) are called when the module is started, the `define` function is there to allow for module definition, but its execution doesn't mean that the module is started.

I've made a fiddle to explain what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Axg27/2/

Comment: I've updated my answer, your comment refers to the old version, sorry about that.

Comment: Does this explanation make sense to you? Your question has been also mine for quite some time, only now I got it this way.

Comment: Yes! Thanks again. I have not read the docs correctly. Sometimes I find them hard to understand. But thanks to your answer I've got it working now as I expect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I totally glossed over `addInitializer` in the docs, assuming that's what `define` was for.